# How can I test content of :before selector with Jasmine in an Angular 6 project?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a label whose `content` is being set in the `:before` selector, and depending on whether or not a checkbox that is associated with this label is checked, will change the content property of the label.  Is this possible to test using **Jasmine** in my Angular 6 project?

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<input id="myCheck" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
<label for="myCheck" class="label"></label>
```

**CSS**

```
.label{
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.label:before{
    content: 'NOT Checked';
}

.checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox:checked + label:before {
    content: 'Checked';
}
```

**Jasmine Unit Test**

```
it('should say "Checked" when checkbox is checked and "NOT Checked" when not checked', () => {
    const check = el.query(By.css('#myCheck')).nativeElement;
    expect(el.query(By.css('#myCheck + label:before'))).toBe('NOT Checked');

    check.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(el.query(By.css('#myCheck + label:before'))).toBe('Checked');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to get at the `:before` selector using the `window` object and `getComputedStyle`:

```
it('should say "Checked" when checkbox is checked and "NOT Checked" when not checked', () => {
    const check = el.query(By.css('#myCheck')).nativeElement;
    let content = window.getComputedStyle('.label')).nativeElement, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
    expect(content).toBe('NOT Checked');

    check.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    content = window.getComputedStyle('.label')).nativeElement, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
    expect(content).toBe('Checked');
});
```